Sound is not coming from laptop speakers, but works only in headphones
I'm unable hear sound in my laptop. If I connect to blurtooth then I can hear audio. It's not laptop's speaker issue because in Windows everything is fine. I have tried updating the drivers and tested in UEFI. In that test also everything is fine. No problem is detected for speakers and sound also working while testing in the BIOS menu of Windows.

If you really tried "all solution," then you already know the troubleshooting information we will ask for. Please edit your question to add it.
